# Get everything done

Tags: sentence-meaning, verbs

> It seems even without the kids here, I don’t have enough time to get everything done that I want to do.

Does "get everything done" mean "everything will be done by myself" or "everything will be done by someone?"

Comment: "get everything done" by itself only describes the activities, not who did them. However, in your example, you wrote" "I", which means the same as "by myself".

Answer (score 2):

Everything here is referring to the list of things that the person wanted to get done.  If I had five things on my list, and I completed all five tasks, then I would have completed everything on my list of tasks... so therefore I got everything done.

In this case, where usually the kids take up a lot of time and keep the list of tasks from being completed, the person still has a problem finding enough time to complete the list of tasks even when the kids are gone, so therefore everything on the list does not get done.